# how to create custom admin panel for django

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-templates

**Hi there**

I'm learning to django and I want to create custom admin for my django project 
so I can deliver my project to clients with beautiful admin panel.

Please suggest me some ideas for doing this.
can it be possible with react?

Please share your thoughts

thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is some helpful packages and make django admin so much beauty
[jet](https://jet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [django-cms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/), [django-material-admin](https://github.com/MaistrenkoAnton/django-material-admin)

or you can make a custom admin panel using react, vuejs or angular
and make some CRUD api for admin panel using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) ( but not recommended )